# Achieve template only on const qualifier in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I want to get two classes that differ only on the constness of a parameter.

What I currently do is:
*(This is a dummy minimal example.)*

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(T & t):
        t(t) {
    }

    T & t;
};

class Foo;

using Foo_wrapper = Wrapper<Foo>;
using Const_Foo_wrapper = Wrapper<const Foo>;
```

I would like my **template** to be declared exclusively on Foo, and **to differ only on the const qualifier**.
That would something such as:
*(This is invalid syntax, to try to give the idea.)*

```
class Foo;

template <qualifier Q>
struct Foo_base_wrapper {
    Wrapper(Q Foo & t):
        t(t) {
    }

    Q Foo & t;
};

using Foo_wrapper = Foo_base_wrapper<none>;
using Const_Foo_wrapper = Foo_base_wrapper<const>;
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

*(A near solution may be with concepts, but that would be still more generic and complex, and I don't have C++ 20.)*

Comment: Instead of `Foo/const Foo` you want to use `Foo_wrap<>/Foo_wrap<const>`? Why?

Comment: As written, this is a dummy minimal example. My real need is to write a custom iterator, that uses several underlying classes, and get a const and a mutable version of this iterator.

Comment: That much is understood. It is however not clear why you need a template that works in this specific way. Simply passing `Foo/const Foo` or using a template alias that adds const on whatever you pass in would be the more idiomatic approach. This looks more like an uneccesarily complicated way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `const` keyword alone but you can use template (partial) specialization to control the constness of a type with something like this.

```
enum Qualifier { Mutable, Const };

template<typename T, Qualifier Q>
struct Qualified
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct Qualified<T, Const>
{
    using type = const T;
};

template <Qualifier Q = Mutable>
struct Foo_base_wrapper
{
    using QualifiedFoo = typename Qualified<Foo, Q>::type;

    Foo_base_wrapper(QualifiedFoo & t) : t(t)
    { }

    QualifiedFoo & t;
};

using Foo_wrapper = Foo_base_wrapper<>;  // or explicitly Foo_base_wrapper<Mutable>
using Const_Foo_wrapper = Foo_base_wrapper<Const>;
```

If you don't have to define other wrappers, you can of course use directly Foo in the Qualified template and its specialization.

You may also be interested in the functions [`std::ref / std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to deal with the constness of references.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is smart, neat, and works perfectly!
(Indeed, I need to do this for several classes.)